# kurento-media-server + spring boot + docker crashes appserver

Tags: docker, webrtc

I want to run this kurento example: 
https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-one2one.html

But i have some issues with application server while building it on docker.

The thing is, that kurento-media-server build succesfully, but it's application server crashes.

Commands that I'm using are:

1) `docker run -t  --name kms -p 8889:8888 kurento/kurento-media-server`

2) `docker run -t --name apps -p 8080:8080 docker-apps`

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:06 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-31T12:16:28+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 54M/553M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:
2.1.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project kurento-one2one-call-advanced: An exception
 occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name
 'webSocketHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.
DelegatingWebSocketConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]:
 Factory method 'webSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'callHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
 field 'kurento'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
 bean with name 'kurentoClient' defined in org.kurento.tutorial.one2onecalladv.One2OneCallAdvApp:


Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
     Failed to instantiate [org.kurento.client.KurentoClient]:
     Factory method 'kurentoClient' threw exception; nested exception is
     org.kurento.commons.exception.KurentoException: Exception connecting to KMS: [KurentoClient]
      Exception connecting to WebSocket server ws://127.0.0.1:8889/kurento: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:8889 -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1]
```

Dockerfile that I use is:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER USER1 "USER1@infinte.com"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN apt install apt-utils -y
RUN apt install maven -y
RUN apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre -y
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
WORKDIR kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-advanced/

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT mvn -U clean spring-boot:run -Dkms.url=ws://127.0.0.1:8889/kurento
```

Answer (score 0):

The port 8888 is a Websocket Secure port. You have to use -Dkms.url=**wss**://127.0.0.1:8889/kurento or change your kurento.conf.json in Kurento Server to expose the 8433 port and them you can use a ws:// protocol.